# Testing changing sheet resistance with impurities

Tags: resistance, probe, conductivity

I have a chemical film, and I'm trying to detect the presence of impurities on the film. They should change the resistance. Assuming it does, how do I measure it? I believe the four point probe method might be right, but as far as I can tell that method is for uniform sheets without impurities. Will I be able to detect a particle on one side of the film even if my probes touch on another side? How does an impurity somewhere far away on the sheet affect the resistance close to the probes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the chemical film is mainly an insulator, trying to measure purity with an ohmmeter method may imply high voltage or extremely low currents.

I have found the best dielectric impurity testing measures the discharge of contaminants as they are excited with sufficient electric field either AC (preferred) or DC hitting a conductor surface.

This is often calibrated and measured in picocoulombs , but I have done it successfully in volts from a simple current loop around the source wire connected to coax terminated by 50 Ohms into a high speed scope. The scope can be replaced with a high speed charge amp or peak detector to detect the concentration of contaminants.  There will be a threshold for 1 pulse per minute which then rapidly increases in rate above this threshold.

The effect of HV excitation is a migration of the charged particle which has a different property than the dielectric medium and the mobility in the fluid and its velocity under the E field determines the discharge rate like a geiger counter or a Unijunction relaxation oscillator.

In my case I was using transformer oil with a 50kV/mm ideal threshold and and a supplied rating of 25kV/mm with an actual case of these Partial Discharge (PD) events starting around 16kV/mm which were caused by silicate iron contaminants that were invisible to the naked eye.

A laser particle reflector may be useful to identify in a glass container, contaminant particles and there are Omega ion insulation ohmmeters but I found my test method to be most effective for empirical measurements.

What chemicals are involved?

Comment: Whoa. Ok. I'm not sure yet what the chemicals will be (the chemists are still figuring that out). My role is building a small device that will detect the changes in the chemical film. I should be able to provide the extremely low currents without a problem. Your third paragraph is intriguing and seems like the way to go. Is there a term for this kind of measurement, or articles you could point me to for additional research? I don't even know what to google at this point.

Comment: I used a variety of insulation breakdown test equipment (high voltage very low current) with many different electrodes, ball, plate (P), needle (N) and NP . For your scenario, find out how the film can be fixtured between parallel plates for E field ac excitation and find out the dielectric constant and its polarization properties. Then experiment with any dielectric of similar resistance with HiV ac stepup autotransformer from an old car (gain ~1k) to experiment with between parallel plates using kV/mm breakdown results and look for PD events before BDV

Comment: A contaminant free dielectric will have NO PD events before breakdown voltage is reached and every test will give exactly the same result. If there is variation, then there are contaminants and will be PD events with a slow ramp up just before expected BDV. In plastic caps, they are designed to be "self healing ""discharges and the best Japanese caps , I expect are tested this way for material contamination which is crucial to achieve rated hiV ratings in plastic caps

Comment: can you give a clue on the purpose of the film or reason for avoiding contaminants?

Comment: It's a small chemical sensor. Think of something like a chemical CO2 sensor. Insert a test strip coated with the chemical film into the thing you want to test, and see if the chemical is present.

Comment: so the chemical is the contaminant? or the substrate missing partial coating? or impurities in the coating?

Comment: shoot, I was ambiguous. Plastic substrate coated with a special chemical film. When dipped in a material, a specific contaminant will react or bind with the film. I need to measure the film to detect the presence of the contaminant.

Comment: In your  case the dielectric constant, d  must be different , preferably lower and thus become a "void" with lower capacitance that breaks down sooner with PD than the rest of the medium. If higher it will go undetected as the voltage drop is less. With sufficient energy, the contaminant may be ignited and converted to a gas molecule. In oil it is H2 and since plastic comes from oil, I would expect the same being the lightest gas. With sufficient low energy butnhigh voltage only H2 is released invisibly